# who manages the features of japanese SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Stackoverflow has a documentation section. That isnt available in japanese SE and in other SE communities. Are the features/settings of japanese SE managed by the moderators? or are they managed by higher levels? (Like SE admins, employees, or whatever)

Comment: [Related Discussion](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1616/542). The mods here can't change the features of the site. Personally I hope we can get the documentation feature.